# Как в VBA указать количество цифр после запятой?

Tags: vba

Пытаюсь сделать что бы после считывания значения из ячейки было определенное количество знаков после запятой у значения. Мне нужно что бы в Count было 2 знака после запятой всегда, а в WeightNetto и SummNetto что бы всегда выводило 3 знака после запятой, даже если там будут все 
 нули, как это сделать?

```
Dim Count        As Double
Dim WeightNetto  As Double
Dim SummNetto    As Double

For i = 2 To LastRowOpenDbfSheet

    Count = Math.Round(CDbl(sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 12)), 2) // Попробовал так но не работает
    WeightNetto = CDbl(sheetOpenDbf.Cells(i, 19))
    SummNetto = Count * WeightNetto
```

Comment: *Мне нужно что бы в Count было 2 знака после запятой всегда, а в WeightNetto и SummNetto что бы всегда выводило 3 знака после запятой* Не перемешивайте ЗНАЧЕНИЕ  и его ОТОБРАЖЕНИЕ. Это принципиально разные вещи, по-разному влияющие на результат. Определите ТОЧНО, что именно требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `VBA` оператор округления - `Round`

```
SummNetto = Round(Count * WeightNetto,3)
```

Для переменной этого достаточно и незначащие нули здесь роли не играют. Округлять не нужно, если требуется округлить только конечный результат.

На листе число тоже будет отображено без ведущих левых и лишних правых нулей (если не задан соответствующий формат ячейки). Для отображения с нулями нужно так и писать - *покажите в формате...*:

```
Cells(1,1).Value = Format(Count * WeightNetto,"0.000")
```

Как бы правильно, но не очень. `Format` приводит значение к текстовому формату. Правильнее не менять числа, а задать формат ячеек в которые выводятся данные (подготовить изначально или изменить макросом перед выводом результата),

Comment: Все числа если были с 1 или 2-я запятыми, то теперь выводятся просто число без запятых. Сейчас добавлю в описание как написал.

Comment: *с 1 или 2-я запятыми* - с двумя - это уже не число. А то, что без запятых - преобразованное в текст значение опять переводилось в числовое. Исправил ответ.